# TFS2010 global build with 2 dependant projects

Tags: build, web

I have 2 TFS Projects (Domain and Web) and I need to let the Domain build first to a common location (C:\Dependencies) and then have the web include that dll. I have unit tests on both the domain and web projects and the build should fail if either test fails.

That means that the location MUST be the same on my local machine as on the TFS build server, is there any way for me to have them different?

I do a Web Transform for web.config but have no idea how to do this to tell the sln that the location of the dependent dll is different. How do I get TFS to build 2 projects from different TFS collections, one after the other? And how do I check out the dll on the server(programmatic) so that the build includes the new one?

Thanks
Jack